# Pyspark PandasUDF assignment

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to evenly parallelise a workload across my workers via a PandasUDF.

The function is rather mem expensive, and I would like each worker to run the function at most *n* times simultaneously. Is there any way I can control how Pyspark distributes the PandasUDF across the workers to achieve this?

For example, let's say I have 20 groups in my Spark DataFrame, and my cluster consists of 5 workers, I would like each worker to execute the udf on 4 groups at the same time:

```
df.groupBy('GROUP_IX').applyInPandas(my_pandas_udf, some_output_schema)
```

I tried repartitioning by range the df beforehand, but that didn't give me the exact uniform workload distribution I'm aiming for (sometimes more than 4 partitions ended up in the same worker):

```
df.repartitionByRange(5, 'GROUP_IX').applyInPandas(my_pandas_udf, some_output_schema)
```

I understand this is not what Pyspark & PandasUDFs are intended for... but I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Spark, by default, will execute as many UDFs per executor as many cores you assign to it, as per the `executor.cores` parameter.

If your application is memory bound you can try setting the `executor.cores` to 1.

Also, consider increasing the memory overhead as PandasUDF are executed outside the JVM spark memory space.

For an UDF application that is CPU bound I still don't have a way to allocate to each UDF more than one CPU.